# Автодополнение в пользовательских программах

Tags: bash, autocomplete

В Linux-е когда через bash запускаешь какую-то программу, то можно используя Tab ускорять ввод параметров, которые нужно передать этой программе. Как сделать так, чтобы автодополнение работало и в моей программе?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/115886/

Answer (score 5):

микропример.

сделаем для нашей (пока несуществующей) программы автодополнение опций `-a`, `-b` и параметра `c` :

```
$ complete -W "-a -b c" x
```

проверяем. вводим `x`, затем пробел, затем символ <kbd>tab</kbd> дважды и видим предложенные варианты:

```
$ x <tab><tab>
-a  -b  c
```

чтобы это работало в каждой сессии, команду (`complete ...`) можно добавить в конец файла `~/.bashrc`.

---

чтобы выполнялось автодополнение именами файлов/каталогов, можно, к примеру, добавить команде *complete* опцию `-f`:

```
$ complete -f -W "-a -b c" x
```

---

а дальше уже надо читать документацию (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) и смотреть на примеры (с актуальными версиями пакета *bash/bash-completion* — в каталоге `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`)

Answer (score 3):

как вариант можете посмотреть примеры в директории

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/*
```

В 16 UBUNTU autocomplete программ расположены в директории

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/
```

Более подробно [тут](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion)